# VSTO: Event Handler failing to fire after a reboot

Tags: c#, event-handling, vsto, outlook-addin

I've come across a problem in my C# VSTO addin for Outlook.
There is an event handler registered at startup that updates a button on the ribbon of the main explorer Window when an item is selected.  When deployed initially (by Clickonce) the addin works flawlessly.  Changing selection updates the button each and every time.
Code for registering the event handler below:

```
Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler selectionChangeEventHandler;

private void RegisterEvents(Outlook.Explorer Explorer)
{
    try
    {
        log.Debug("Registering Events");
        Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += Explorers_NewExplorer;
        selectionChangeEventHandler = new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(ThisAddIn_SelectionChange);
        Explorer.SelectionChange -= selectionChangeEventHandler;
        Explorer.SelectionChange += selectionChangeEventHandler;
        this.Application.OptionsPagesAdd -= Application_OptionsPagesAdd;
        this.Application.OptionsPagesAdd += Application_OptionsPagesAdd;
        Application.ItemSend -= Application_ItemSend;
        Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
        log.Debug("Events Registration Succeeded");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         log.Debug("Event Registration Failed");
         log.Error(ex.Message);
         log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
     }
 }

 private void Explorers_NewExplorer(Outlook.Explorer Explorer)
 {
     RegisterEvents(Explorer);
 }
```

With the registration method being invoked like this

```
 RegisterEvents(Application.ActiveExplorer());
```

However after a reboot the event handler fires twice and then never fires again.

To attempt to track the issue down I added a line to start the debugger if a string is set in the app.config (as below)

```
if (String.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("attachDebugger"), "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    Debugger.Launch();
```

After a reboot I can start Outlook and watch the plugin fail to update the selection.  In then close Outlook, toggle the attachDebugger flag in the config and the button immediately starts working.

All other functionality in the addin works, so it's not a case that the addin is coming to a grinding halt.

I'm at a loss to know what to do next.  If anyone has startling insight into why an event handler should run differently before and after a reboot (incidentally uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin causes it to work again for that session), I'd be very grateful.  I'd also welcome anyones advice who can suggest methods for debugging an application when the problem fails to manifest under a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a global (class) variable that stores a pointer to the Explorer object. Otherwise it gets released by the Garbage Collector. If you don't, it fires events only before it is released.

Comment: Thank you, that has solved the problem.  It's interesting that the GC works differently just after installation.  I can understand GC functioning differently under debugging (to retain handles to historic events for example), but for that to change just from being installed has me puzzled.

Comment: That's the thing about the GC - it is non-deterministic. It is guaranteed to clean things up, you just don't know when.